# SMTP showing error after sending few mails to user from localhost

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am working with phpmailer and smtp to send mail from local host to gmail. The problem is firstly i send mail and it was working fine but now its giving smtp connection failed. Here is my code. I am new to this, kindly help me out.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'smag.ghaznavi1@gmail.com';          // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->SMTPDebug=2;
    $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'PMS');
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'CodexWorld');
    $mail->addAddress('smag.ghaznavi1@gmail.com');   // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

    $bodyContent = '<h1>Your password reset link</h1>';
    $bodyContent .= "Dear user,\n\nIf this e-mail does not apply to you please ignore it. It appears that you have requested a password reset at our website www.yoursitehere.com\n\nTo reset your password, please click the link below. If you cannot click it, please paste it into your web browser's address bar.\n\n" . $pwrurl . "\n\nThanks,\nThe Administration";

    $mail->Subject = 'Email from Project Management System Admin';
    $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }



smag.ghaznavi1@gmail.com2018-07-04 16:43:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 
smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o4-v6sm5724500wmo.20 - gsmtp
2018-07-04 16:43:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-07-04 16:43:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, 
[39.54.130.23]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250- 
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-07-04 16:43:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-07-04 16:43:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-07-04 16:43:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-07-04 16:43:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-07-04 16:43:59 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: You need to be careful using gmail as an smtp server relay https://serversmtp.com/limits-of-gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: @Hackerman i am not having limit exceed error. Its smtp failed

Answer (score 0):

Check if enabled **"Allow less secure apps"** in your google account - [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

Also try to enter in your google account and visit page **"displayCaptcha"** - [link](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

And you should provide your code to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's failing to start TLS, which is usually an indicator that your CA certificates are out of date, especially when using Gmail. It's nothing to do with the "less secure apps" setting or the captcha issue - though you may run into those later.

Follow [the link to the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) in the error message which describes this exact error, and tells you how to fix it (by updating your CA certs - **not** by disabling certificate verification!). It's uncanny, almost as if that link was there purely to help you resolve problems like this without having to ask questions and wait for answers...